# SQL Query to Return Count Based on Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting problem and am unsure how to write a query to solve it.  Say I have a table named "Cars".  It has two columns, CarId (int PK), and ArrivalTime (datetime).  As cars enter a space, the arrival time is entered.

What I need to know is this: for each car, how many entered the space in the 24 time period prior to it's arrival.

I'd like to write this without using a cursor, but don't know how I can do it.  Any SQL gurus out there with an idea?

Oh - I should mention that the SQL Server version being used is 2005.

Comment: Sample data will take you far... help us help you.

Comment: I am assuming your question is  - "What I need to know is this: for each car, how many "Other Cars" entered the same space in the 24 time period prior to it's arrival."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a query with either a correlated subquery or a join.

Here's an example of query using a join operation:

```
SELECT n.CarId
     , n.ArrivalDate
     , COUNT(p.CarId) AS cnt_previous_arrivals
  FROM cars n
  LEFT
  JOIN cars p
    ON p.CarId = n.CarId
   AND p.ArrivalDate >= DATEADD(HOUR,-24,n.ArrivalDate)
   AND p.ArrivalDate < n.ArrivalDate
 GROUP
    BY n.CarId
     , n.ArrivalDate
```

To get an equivalent result with correlated subquery, one option:

```
SELECT n.CarId
     , n.ArrivalDate
     , ( SELECT SUM(1) 
           FROM cars p 
          WHERE p.CarId = n.CarId
            AND p.ArrivalDate >= DATEADD(HOUR,-24,n.ArrivalDate)
            AND p.ArrivalDate < n.ArrivalDate
       ) AS cnt_previous_arrivals
  FROM cars n
 ORDER
    BY n.CarId
     , n.ArrivalDate
```

Comment: EDIT: I added ArrivalDate to the GROUP BY clause in the JOIN query (missed that the first time through, and added an example of a correlated subquery)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I used to work in SQL 24/7.  It's amazing how much gets lost in a few years time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select el1.car_id,
       ( select count(*)
           from entry_log el2
          where el2.datetime between DATEADD(day, -1, el1.datetime)
                 and el1.datetime
             and el2.car_id != el1. car_id 
        )
  from entry_log el1
where el1.car_id = :my_car_id
```